# Remove blinking cursor from styled input button

Tags: styling, submit-button

I'm styling all input submit buttons with the following classes:

```
.button {
    background: #E2F0FE;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin: 5px 0 0;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    cursor: pointer}
.button:hover { background-color: #0281FF; }
```

But when a button is clicked on the blinking text cursor shows on the button and as long as the button has focus the cursor continues to blink in the text of the button.

Is there anyway to prevent that behavior?

Answer (score 2):

firefox has a Caret Browsing feature, toggled by F7 ... [read more](http://www.blog.highub.com/firefox-4/firefox-blinking-cursor/) ... so in your case (as mine) you must have hit the F7 on your keyboard at some point in the past, and now you are getting the blinking cursor ... but it should be happening on all firefox pages.

I used firebug to try and find the actual textfield where the blinking cursor was located, but I didn't find one ... ghost textfield.